# Fill form based on selection in dropdown list php

Tags: php, mysql

I have done quite a bit of research on this one with no success. So what I'm currently looking to do is:

1. Populate a dropdown list based off of a table in the database (Already finished)
2. After choosing a value from the dropdown list that was generated from the database I'd like to allow the user to edit the record by autofilling what it currently has and allowing them to change the content that is stored in the database, or just click a button to delete the record. (Not complete)

The Database object is an Album an has the following properties

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| AlbumID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| AlbumName   | varchar(75) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Label       | varchar(75) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Genre       | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ReleaseDate | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Artist      | varchar(75) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The HTML I'm currently trying to work with is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyMuzik Library</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/site.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#txtReleaseDate").mask("9999/99/99",{placeholder:"yyyy/mm/dd"});
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insertAlbum.php" method="post">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="fphome.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="fpsongs.php">Songs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
    <form action="insertAlbum.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <h1>Albums</h1>
        <h3>This is where you add new albums</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddlAlbumSelect" id="lblAlbumSelect">Select Album to Edit:</label>
        <div class="form-control">
            <select name="ddlAlbumSelect" id="ddlAlbumSelect">
                <option value="0"> Select Album...</option>
                <?php
                    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1978afc247a');
                    mysql_select_db('finalproject');
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums ORDER BY AlbumName");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['AlbumID'] . "'>" . $row['AlbumName'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtAlbumName" id="lblAlbumName">Album Name:</label>
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" <?php if(ddlAlbumSelect.Value != 0) echo "<p>Selected a value!</p>" ?>  name="txtAlbumName" id="txtAlbumName" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtArtist" id="lblArtist">Artist:</label>
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" name="txtArtist" id="txtArtist" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtLabel" id="lblLabel">Label:</label>
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" name="txtLabel" id="txtLabel" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtGenre" id="lblGenre">Genre:</label>
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" name="txtGenre" id="txtGenre" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtReleaseDate" id="lblReleaseDate">Release Date:</label>
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" name="txtReleaseDate" id="txtReleaseDate" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <input style="margin-left:30px" type="submit" />
</form>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br />
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>MyMuzik Library&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The form action file referenced called insertAlbum.php is seen below as well:

```
<html>
<body>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1978afc247a");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("finalproject", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO albums (AlbumName, Label, Genre, ReleaseDate, Artist)
VALUES
('$_POST[txtAlbumName]','$_POST[txtLabel]', '$_POST[txtGenre]','$_POST[txtReleaseDate]','$_POST[txtArtist]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added <br/>";

mysql_close($con)
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>"><< Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using AJAX but have been unsuccessful, just looking for a kick in the right direction! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have at least provided your `Ajax` effort. Anyway, below is my answer. I have put my explanations in a comment form.

#### POPULATE TEXT FIELDS BASED FROM SELECTED ALBUM:

```
$(document).on("change", "#ddlAlbumSelect", function(){ /* WHEN AN ALBUM HAS BEEN SELECTED */

  var albumid = $(this).val(); /* GET THE ID OF THE SELECTED ALBUM */

  $.ajax({ /* START OF AJAX */
    type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
    url: "getalbum.php", /* THE FILE WHERE WE WILL PROCESS THE PASSED DATA */
    data: {"albumid": albumid}, /* DATA TO BE PASSED */
    dataType: "json", /* TYPE OF DATA THAT WILL BE RETURNED FROM getalbum.php */
    success: function(result){ /* GET RETURNED DATA FROM getalbum.php */
      /* BELOW WILL POPULATE THE CORRESPONDING TEXT FIELDS IN YOUR FORM */
      $("#txtAlbumName").val(result.albumName);
      $("#txtArtist").val(result.artist);
      $("#txtLabel").val(result.label);
      $("#txtGenre").val(result.genre);
      $("#txtReleaseDate").val(result.releaseDate);
    } /* END OF GETTING THE RETURNED DATA FROM getalbum.php */
  }); /* END OF AJAX */

});
```

Then the `getalbum.php`:

```
/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "1978afc247a", "finalproject");

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT txtAlbumName, txtLabel, txtGenre, txtReleaseDate, txtArtist FROM albums WHERE AlbumID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["albumid"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($albumname, $label, $genre, $releasedate, $artist);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

echo json_encode(array("albumName" => $albumname, "label" => $label, "genre" => $genre, "releaseDate" => $releasedate, "artist" => $artist"));
```

Refrain from using [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API and use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

#### UPDATING THE ALBUM:

I thought you are trying to update the selected album? Why is your form going to `insertAlbum.php`?

Comment: My plan was to change the Query to be more of a save instead of an insert. And my AJAX attempt was so bad I didn't even want to show it to the world. Ha sorry about that.

Comment: Added the getalbum.php and put the js code into the main php file with no success. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you establish a `mysqli_*` database connection in your getalbum.php? What is the error you are getting in your console log? (Hit F12 in your browser to see console log)

Comment: When I select a value in the dropdown list, nothing happens. No redirection or anything. And yes I established the connection in the php file.

Comment: Look for errors in your console log and I've updated my answer with database connection.

Comment: The only error I'm seeing is "ReferenceError: Artist is not defined"

Comment: @Oystermaker Then, that is the error. When does the error show? When you select an album from the `<select>`?

Comment: Nothing happens when I select an album.

Comment: Did you just copy+paste my answer? Because I don't have an `Artist` in the script. I have `artist`, and not `Artist`. And I'm asking when does the error show in the console log? Does it show in the console log when you select an album?

Comment: But Artist is the only one it's complaining about? There is no error from what I'm seeing

Comment: Did you fix the error? Remember that JS variables are case sensitive. And script won't run properly if you have errors in your console log.